# Displaying parts of main menu in separate blocks

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I need to display my main menu in separate blocks: the first sub-menu in one block, and the following two sub-menus in another block. I'm using Drupal's native menu module and also the [nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [menu_block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) and defining 2 blocks with the depths you desire within the main-menu for each block; and then place them in the drupal Regions you want. The menu_blocks I believe will play nicely with [Nice Menus](http://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus) if you have "expand all child elements" of this menu option checked.